# How to computer range from loss factor

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to understand the following code given in MediumLimitCache.cc file to understand the formula of finding communication range using loss factor. I know for isotropic antenna, `FSPL = Pt/Pr = (4*pi*d*f/c)^2`. I could not understand how this formula is implemented in below code.

Would anyone please explain me the functions of the below code? Thank you.

```
m MediumLimitCache::computeMaxRange(W maxTransmissionPower, W minReceptionPower) const
{
    // TODO: this is NaN by default
    Hz centerFrequency = Hz(par("centerFrequency"));
    **double loss = unit(minReceptionPower / maxTransmissionPower).get() / maxAntennaGain / maxAntennaGain; 
    return radioMedium->getPathLoss()->computeRange(radioMedium->getPropagation()->getPropagationSpeed(), centerFrequency, loss);**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula is NOT implemented in this code. This is MediumLimitCache i.e. this is just an optimization component that requires a maximum estimation.

You might find more info inside the `computeRange()` method.

Comment: Hi Rudi, in ```computeRange()```, I can see two extra terms ```systemLoss``` and ```alpha``` [```return m(pow((waveLength * waveLength).get() / (16.0 * M_PI * M_PI * systemLoss * loss), 1.0 / alpha));]```, would you please say what these terms for? Thank you.